# Configure managed identities for Azure resources

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I have a few services with two deployment kinds: Virtual Machine Scale Set and RDFE based deployments.

I want to add managed identities to those services, but I'm a bit puzzled about how to do so for the second type of deployment (RDFE-based).

I've looked [at this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

It stated that using MSI extension would be deprecated in 1.19 but it doesn't seem like IMDS supports PaaS deployments.

How should I add the managed identities to RDFE deployment and what endpoint should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Managed identities are not supported on RDFE deployments, since we depend on Azure Resource Manager for configuration of the identity.

Comment: Thanks, could you please point me to the solution I should use for RDFE deployments?

Comment: Then how do we keep our secrets out of our code? It seems pretty silly that a service principal couldn't leverage Managed Identity.

Comment: For RDFE deployments, you can use pure service principals. I wish I had a better answer for you here.

And to clarify, each managed identities has a backing service principals. The dependency on Azure Resource Manager is for getting the managed identity + service principal securely configured onto the resource where the managed identity will be used.